# Do the following show I bought a used mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a mac on July 17, 2016. I read that this command can tell if the first user of this mac was myself:

```
ls -lt /private/var/db/ | tail -30
```

Then it shows 30 lists. Some of them are easy to understand, but there are many that I don't know what they mean. Some also have strange dates within them as follows:

The first few lists look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                237  8  2  2015 QuickTimePlayerVersion.plist
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  8  2  2015 gke.sigs
```

The lists in the middle look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x    4 root             wheel                136  7  7  2016 mds
drwx--x--x    4 root             wheel                136  7  7  2016 TokenCache
```

On the date I bought this Mac, this occurs:

```
drwxr-xr-x    5 root             wheel                170  7 17  2016 ConfigurationProfiles
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  7 17  2016 DetachedSignatures
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102  7 17  2016 efw_cache
```

**Do these list entries prove that the Mac I purchased had been used before?**

Edit:
I use Klanomath's suggestion. I input the following command,

```
ls -altUT /private/var/db/
```

The output:

```
total 21536

-rw-r-----    1 root             wheel                 53 12  7 21:02:26 2017 kcm-dump.bin
-r--r--r--    1 nobody           wheel            9495749 12  2 09:53:47 2017 locate.database
-rw-------    1 root             wheel              79904 11 21 20:56:12 2017 BootCache.playlist
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102 10 28 02:18:07 2017 gkopaque.bundle
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel              27040  5 27 16:07:23 2017 com.apple.almigration.keychain
-r--r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  5 27 16:07:21 2017 .flC0BE2792
drwx------    3 root             wheel                102  7 23 15:18:36 2016 sudo
-rw-------    1 root             wheel             750113  7 23 05:02:19 2016 dslocal-backup.xar
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  7  7 18 09:57:46 2016 ntp.drift
-rw-r-----    1 root             wheel                 16  7 18 09:00:39 2016 kcm-dump.uuid
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                230  7 18 08:31:24 2016 SystemPolicy-prefs.plist
drwxr-xr-x   68 root             wheel               2312  7 17 21:19:57 2016 receipts
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102  7 17 21:19:54 2016 efw_cache
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                181  7 17 17:39:11 2016 .LastGKReject
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                288  7 17 17:38:31 2016 .GKRearmTimer
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  7 17 17:26:40 2016 DetachedSignatures
-r--------    1 root             wheel                  0  7 17 17:18:53 2016 .AppleDiagnosticsSetupDone
-r--------    1 root             wheel                  0  7 17 17:16:56 2016 .AppleSetupDone
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel               1196  7  7 01:26:50 2016 .com.apple.iokit.graphics
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  7  7 01:26:49 2016 .configureLocalKDC
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                 54  7  7 01:26:47 2016 volinfo.database
drwxr-xr-x    6 root             wheel                204  7  7 01:26:30 2016 awdd
drwxr-xr-x@   7 root             wheel                238  7  7 01:26:29 2016 CoreDuet
drwx------    4 root             wheel                136  7  7 01:26:29 2016 dhcpclient
-r--------    1 root             wheel                 48  7  7 01:26:28 2016 SystemKey
drwxr-xr-x    2 root             wheel                 68  7  7 01:26:26 2016 PanicReporter
drwx--x--x    4 root             wheel                136  7  7 01:26:26 2016 TokenCache
-rw-------    1 root             wheel             126976  7  7 01:26:26 2016 auth.db
-rw-------    1 root             wheel              32768  7  7 01:26:26 2016 auth.db-shm
-rw-------    1 root             wheel             115392  7  7 01:26:26 2016 auth.db-wal
drwxr-xr-x    4 root             wheel                136  7  7 01:26:26 2016 mds
-rw-------    1 root             wheel                 20  7  7 01:26:25 2016 SystemEntropyCache
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel               1375  5  5 17:04:37 2016 .MASManifest
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                284  5  5 17:04:31 2016 PartNumber.plist
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  5  5 16:07:34 2016 .AppleCustomMac
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  5  5 16:07:33 2016 .RunLanguageChooserToo
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                233  5  5 16:01:07 2016 .AppleInstallType.plist
drwx------    5 root             wheel                170  5  5 15:57:21 2016 Spotlight
drwxr-xr-x    8 root             wheel                272  5  5 15:55:05 2016 spindump
drwxr-xr-x   68 root             wheel               2312  5  5 14:07:04 2016 .
drwxr-xr-x   24 root             wheel                816  5  5 14:05:44 2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x    4 _displaypolicyd  _displaypolicyd      136  4 20 12:27:31 2016 displaypolicyd
-r--------    1 root             wheel                  0  4 20 10:40:43 2016 BootCache.data
-r--r--r--    1 root             wheel              61440  4 20 09:21:48 2016 .SystemPolicy-default
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel             225280  4 20 09:21:48 2016 SystemPolicy
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102  4 15 08:55:43 2016 FIPS
drwxr-xr-x    8 root             wheel                272  4  3 11:54:28 2016 com.apple.xpc.launchd
drwxr-x---    4 _locationd       _locationd           136  2 26 06:50:25 2016 locationd
drwx------    9 _usbmuxd         _usbmuxd             306  2 26 06:50:25 2016 lockdown
drwxr-x---    3 _nsurlsessiond   _nsurlsessiond       102  2 26 06:50:25 2016 nsurlsessiond
drwxr-x---    3 _securityagent   _securityagent       102  2 26 06:50:25 2016 securityagent
drwxr-xr-x    5 root             wheel                170  2 26 06:50:24 2016 ConfigurationProfiles
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102  2 26 06:50:24 2016 caches
drwxr-xr-x    3 root             wheel                102  2 26 06:50:24 2016 dslocal
drwxr-x---    2 _geod            _geod                 68  2 26 06:50:24 2016 geod
drwxr-xr-x  168 root             wheel               5712  2 26 06:50:24 2016 systemstats
drwxr-xr-x    2 _astris          _astris               68  2 26 06:50:14 2016 astris
drwxr-x---    2 root             wheel                 68  2 26 06:50:14 2016 diagnostics
drwxr-xr-x    2 _ondemand        _ondemand             68  2 26 06:50:14 2016 ondemand
drwxr-xr-x   10 root             wheel                340 12  5 09:31:10 2015 crls
drwxr-xr-x    8 root             wheel                272 10 24 10:51:30 2015 BootCaches
drwxr-xr-x@   8 root             wheel                272 10 24 07:10:13 2015 dyld
drwxr-xr-x    4 root             wheel                136 10  4 08:42:00 2015 openldap
drwxr-xr-x    2 root             wheel                 68  8  2 14:21:42 2015 emondClients
drwxrwx---    3 root             admin                102  8  2 12:13:58 2015 GPURestartReporter
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel             297813  8  2 10:48:01 2015 gke.auth
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  0  8  2 10:47:58 2015 gke.sigs
-rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                237  8  2 10:45:21 2015 QuickTimePlayerVersion.plist
```

Comment: Where does it say that command shows you are the first user. On mine and I am the only user all dates are OK but all are much newer than when I first used it

Comment: What model Mac do you have?

Comment: @Allan MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) - Technical Specifications. This is a link https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?viewlocale=en_US&locale=zh_CN

Comment: It's a two year old Mac so the dates on the OS would be valid.  The bigger question is *what would lead you to believe this was new/unused given that it's two years old?*

Comment: The example in my answer was an erase disk & fresh install with a d/led installer ~one year ago. Your output looks like a fresh system image applied in the factory. I can't proof this though because I don't have a virgin MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) or a newer untouched model lying around here to check this. And I don't really remember the first boot of my latest Mac.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it doesn't show that you got a "used" (or second-hand) Mac but it was probably booted at least once to the Setup Assistant 10 days before you bought it.

The two oldest files (QuickTimePlayerVersion.plist & gke.sigs) are original files also present in the El Capitan 10.11.0 as well as the El Capitan 10.11.6 installer package with the same modification date. They don't indicated whether a Mac was booted or not.

After booting a Mac for the first time Setup Assistant.app pops up and asks you to set-up locales, time zone, network configuration etc. and finally the first user.

This creates several files and folders in /private/var/db - especially /private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone which indicates a successful finalization of the set-up.

---

A better command than `ls -lt /private/var/db/` is `ls -altUT /private/var/db/` which shows the (complete) creation dates sorted from new to old after a (then) fresh El Capitan install (but **no upgrade** to Sierra or High Sierra afterwards):

```
…
drwx------     4 root             wheel                136 Sep 25 20:33:28 2016 sudo
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                288 Sep 25 20:23:44 2016 .GKRearmTimer
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel              36864 Sep 25 20:23:44 2016 DetachedSignatures
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                229 Sep 25 20:23:44 2016 SystemPolicy-prefs.plist
-r--------     1 root             wheel                  0 Sep 25 20:22:10 2016 .AppleDiagnosticsSetupDone
-r--------     1 root             wheel                  0 Sep 25 20:21:30 2016 .AppleSetupDone
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel               2157 Sep 25 20:19:20 2016 .com.apple.iokit.graphics
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                  0 Sep 25 20:19:20 2016 .configureLocalKDC
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                182 Sep 25 20:19:18 2016 .MASManifest
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                 54 Sep 25 20:19:18 2016 volinfo.database
drwxr-xr-x     6 root             wheel                204 Sep 25 20:19:08 2016 awdd
drwx------     4 root             wheel                136 Sep 25 20:19:08 2016 dhcpclient
drwxr-xr-x@    7 root             wheel                238 Sep 25 20:19:07 2016 CoreDuet
-r--------     1 root             wheel                 48 Sep 25 20:19:07 2016 SystemKey
drwxr-xr-x     2 root             wheel                 68 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 PanicReporter
-rw-------     1 root             wheel                 20 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 SystemEntropyCache
drwx--x--x     4 root             wheel                136 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 TokenCache
-rw-------     1 root             wheel             147456 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 auth.db
-rw-------     1 root             wheel              32768 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 auth.db-shm
-rw-------     1 root             wheel              45352 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 auth.db-wal
drwxr-xr-x     4 root             wheel                136 Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 mds
-rw-r--r--     1 root             wheel                233 Sep 25 20:18:12 2016 .AppleInstallType.plist
drwx------     7 root             wheel                238 Sep 25 20:17:20 2016 Spotlight
drwxr-xr-x    48 root             wheel               1632 Sep 25 20:13:19 2016 spindump
drwxr-xr-x    29 root             wheel                986 Sep 25 20:03:22 2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x    73 root             wheel               2482 Jul  9 05:00:54 2016 .
drwxr-xr-x     2 _displaypolicyd  _displaypolicyd       68 Jun 24 03:55:56 2016 displaypolicyd
…
```

The first line `… sudo` indicates the first shell user interaction - I set the hostname - visible in this folder.

The last two lines `… .` and `… displaypolicyd` are the original creation dates from inside the OS X installer.

All other files and folders are dynamically built while booting, installing and setting up the system for the first time.

Important steps reflected in **this** folder:

- Installing: `… Sep 25 20:03:22 2016 ..`
- Intermediate steps:

  ```
  … Sep 25 20:17:20 2016 Spotlight
  … Sep 25 20:13:19 2016 spindump
  ```
- Booting/Installation finished > Setup Assistant (first step)

  ```
  … Sep 25 20:19:06 2016 mds
  ```
- Setup done:

  ```
  … Sep 25 20:21:30 2016 .AppleSetupDone
  ```

Even if you set up your Mac (with the  Setup Assistant) with leisure the lapse between the creation date of *mds* and *.AppleSetupDone* shouldn't be more than 10 minutes. In my example it was two and a half minute.

---

In your case the Mac probably was booted once, 10 days (July 7, 2016) before you bought it (July 17, 2016). Based on your less suitable command and the fragmentary output it's unclear though whether a user was created or not, and deleted later.

Comment: Thank you. I input your suggested command and add the output to the question.